# Bring down interface of running container (without --privileged)

Tags: docker, networking, containers

How can an interface of a running container be brought down keeping in mind that it was not started/deployed with -- privileged flag ? I know very well if the container is running with --privileged flag it will allow you else it will throw error as "Operation not permitted" as below:

```
root@be90baf1d5f5:/# ip link delete eth0
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

I have heard that using namespace this can be achieved but not much idea about it.

N.B: Please don't provide links to stackoverflow for this context, I have already seen them. I'm talking about a running container not having --privileged flag. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why you want to do that and what is that you are looking to achieve?

Comment: Let's say we have a container running in production and suddenly due to some network problem some of the interfaces start behaving weird. We need to may be restart/fix interfaces as we do for physical hosts. I'm just trying to test that.

Comment: Then not a question related to programming. post it on https://unix.stackexchange.com/